# How do I git pull and push to different locations

Tags: git, github

I am maintaining a fork of a git repo on github. I have two remotes: `origin` which points to the original location and `fork` which points to my github repo.

I pushed to github following their help with `git push -u fork master`. It worked but it mentioned something about modifying a remote. How do I pull from the origin and push to github ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are ways to preset these kinds of things, but I'd probably just stick with the classic:

```
git pull origin master ;# to pull 'master' from origin
git push fork master ;# to push 'master' to fork
```

I don't particularly like setting upstream branches, but that's just because I'm cantankerous and like explicit ref specification. I also skip `git pull` entirely in favor of `git fetch` and `git merge` and those kids had best get off my lawn.